# Bit shift and XOR function of two ints

Tags: python, bit, bit-shift, xor

I have quite a weird operation in my programme.
Given are two numbers a and b in binary.
The second number tells how many summands I built, namely the amount of 1s in the number. Their positions (powers of 2) tell how far a gets shifted before getting a new summand.

Example:

```
    a = 1100101
    b =   10110
 index= 6543210
```

b has a 1 at the indices 1, 2 and 4 (from right to left), so the summands are (filling with zeros), being shifts of a:

```
(a << 1), (a << 2), (a << 4)
```

Those get XORed all together:
(a << 1) ^ (a << 2) ^ (a << 4)

Second example:

```
a = 110101
b =  10101
```

Result:

```
(a << 0) ^ (a << 2) ^ (a << 4)
```

Normally, I would now order a and b such that b is shorter, then for-loop over the indices of b and put shifted summands into an array and go over the array to XOR them in the end.

But isn't there a smoother way for doing that?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it, try rephrasing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I rephrased it and put a second example in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, Python isn't the best choice for stuff like this.

```
res = 0  # this is where the result will be
while b:
    b, flag = divmod(b, 2)
    res ^= a*flag
    a <<= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using reduce from functools

```
from functools import reduce
a = 0b1100101
b = 0b10101
print( reduce(lambda a,x: a^x, (a << i for i in range(len(bin(b))-2) if (b&(1<<i))>0),0) )
```

the (a << i for i in range(len(bin(b))-2) expression gives you the shifted a numbers you then use reduce to xor all the numbers together starting with an initial value of 0 as that will not change the bit pattern

```
>>> [ i for i in range(len(bin(b))-2) if (b & (1<<i))>0 ]
[1, 2, 4]

>>> [a << i for i in range(len(bin(b))-2) if (b & (1<<i))>0 ]
[202, 404, 1616]

>>> reduce(lambda a,x: a^x, (a << i for i in range(len(bin(b))-2) if (b&(1<<i))>0),0)
1806
```

Edit

the answer provided by Marat is much faster

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from functools import reduce; a=0b1100101; b=0b10110' 'reduce(lambda a,x: a^x, (a << i for i in range(len(bin(b))-2) if (b&(1<<i))>0),0)'
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.01 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'res=0; a=0b1100101; b=0b10110' 'while b: b, flag = divmod(b, 2); res ^= a*flag; a <<= 1'
20000000 loops, best of 5: 18.5 nsec per loop
```